# partials are not getting removed from cache in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this folder partials in my angularjs project, I have uploaded the project on the server using the ftp. When i update anything in my partials folder nothing is getting update on the server i tried appending the random string , but still was helpless , i have also changed the version of my angular app in my static folder still was helpless.

app.config(function($interpolateProvider,$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');

$stateProvider
    .state('trainings', {
        url: '/trainings',
        templateUrl: '/partials/trainings.html'
    })
  .state('studentdata', {
        url: '/studentdata',
        templateUrl: '/partials/studentdata.html?cache-bust=' + cacheBustSuffix
    })
    .state('eventupdate', {
        url: '/eventupdate',
        templateUrl: '/partials/eventupdate.html'
    })
```

cacheBustSuffix i created a random string in that but still was helpless. Please help me out